# SQL compilation error-- Snowsql validation using python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, validation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following this tutorial :https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

to try and 'return errors by query ID and saves the results to a table for future reference'

however for a seamless transfer I don't want to be putting the job id always as it would require me to go to snowflake console- go to history- get the jobid -copy and paste it to python code.

Instead I wanted to go with just the tablename which is a variable and 'last_query_id()' and give me the list errors. Is there any way i can achieve this?

```
import snowflake.connector
tableName='F58155'

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='*',
password='*',
account='*')

cs = ctx.cursor()

ctx.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE STORE_PROFILE_LANDING")
ctx.cursor().execute("USE SCHEMA PUBLIC")

try:
    ctx.cursor().execute("PUT file:///temp/data/{tableName}/* @% 
        {tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))
except Exception:
pass

ctx.cursor().execute("truncate table {tableName}".format(tableName=tableName))

ctx.cursor().execute("COPY INTO {tableName} ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE'  ".format(tableName=tableName, 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '""', sometimes=',', ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = 'TRUE'))
```

I have tried the below validate function....it is giving me error on this line

the error is "SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 74 unexpected 'tableName'.
syntax error line 1 at position 83 unexpected '}'."

```
ctx.cursor().execute("create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from 
table(validate({tableName},'select last_query_id()'))");


ctx.close()
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @demircioglu SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 74 unexpected 'tableName'.
syntax error line 1 at position 83 unexpected '}'.

Comment: Your SQL is not constructed properly. You either need `.format(tableName=tableName)` to bind the variable or use f string notation which is easier to read. So it will look like this `ctx.cursor().execute(f"create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from 
table(validate({tableName},'select last_query_id()'))");`.  I also think you need `job_id=>` after tableName`

Comment: @demircioglu Tried this query --- ctx.cursor().execute(f"create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from table(validate({tableName}, job_id=> 'select last_query_id();'))") . it is giving me an error as this-- "Invalid argument [Invalid Job UUID provided.] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.
"

Comment: In this case run a sql to get the job UUID and pass it to the validate sql   To get the job_id `job_id = ctx.cursor().execute("select last_query_id()").fetchone()[0]`   And you can you run validate sql as `ctx.cursor().execute(f"create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from  table(validate({tableName},hob_id=>'{job_id}'))");`

Comment: If would likely be far easier to use the .sfqid attribute of your cursor object to get the value and then plug that into your validate table function.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#sfqid

Comment: @demircioglu great! this logic works well!!!! Thanks so much

Comment: @AshitaRamteke Glad to help, posted as an answer, up to you to select as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
ctx.cursor().execute("create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from 
table(validate({tableName},'select last_query_id()'))");
```

should be replaced with these two

```
job_id = ctx.cursor().execute("select last_query_id()").fetchone()[0] 

ctx.cursor().execute(f"create or replace table save_copy_errors as select * from
table(validate({tableName},job_id=>'{job_id}'))");
```